# How can I get html class name using Twig?

Tags: html, twig

I want to get the name of a class using tip and display a certain text based on what the class is. Is there a way to get a class name and use it in an IF condition?

```
<div class="zboruri_rute {{ route_type ? "departure_flight" : 
"arrival_flight" }}">

{% if class == "zboruri_rute departure_flight" %}

<p>Departure</p>

{% elseif if class == "zboruri_rute arrival_flight" %}

<p>Arrival</p>

{% endif %}
```

I want to display Departure if the class is zboruri_intoarcere and display arrival if the class is zboruri_plecare

Comment: Why don't you just use `route_type` in `if`

Comment: I tried this. Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    {% set route_type = "departure_flight" %}
    <div class="zboruri_rute {{ route_type ? "departure_flight" :
    "arrival_flight" }}">

        {% if route_type == "departure_flight" %}

            <p>Departure</p>

        {% elseif  route_type == "arrival_flight" %}

            <p>Arrival</p>

        {% endif %}
```

or with jquery

```
<p id="result"></p>
    <script>
         zboruri_rute = $(".zboruri_rute").attr('class');
         if (zboruri_rute.indexOf("departure_flight") >= 0)
         {$("#result").text("Departure")}
         if (zboruri_rute.indexOf("arrival_flight") >= 0)
         {$("#result").text("Arrival")}
    </script>
```

Comment: How would `route_type` either be `departure flight` or `arrival flight`? Based on the first if this is untrue

Comment: route_type is variable.
 I dont know exactly what is its value.it is example.

Comment: it will never be one of those two's otherwise the class would always be `departure_flight`, followed out of the first `if`. `route_type` will either be `0` or `1`

Comment: This line {% set route_type = "departure_flight" %} only for perform part code. I used that to show to user .how  dose it work .I dont know what happened at others of part's of program.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, by namth, u'd only need to test `route_type` again, e.g.

```
<div class="zboruri_rute {{ route_type ? "departure_flight" : "arrival_flight" }}">
{% if route_type %}
    <p>Departure</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Arrival</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/2o5s29)

---

Shorter version

```
<div class="zboruri_rute {{ route_type ? "departure_flight" : "arrival_flight" }}">
    <p>{{ route_type ? 'Departure': 'Arrival' }}</p>
</div>
```